# Fetch data from text file having different tables and join c#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have text file in the below format:

```
Table1  1   Name      John
Table1  1   SId       110
Table1  1   City      NewYork
Table1  2   Name      Abc
Table1  2   SId       111
Table1  2   City      Paris
Table2  1   SId       110
Table2  1   DeptName  HR
Table2  1   DeptId    00001
Table2  2   SId       111
Table2  2   DeptName  Dev
Table2  2   DeptId    00002
Table3  1   DeptId    00001
Table3  1   DeptHead  Adam
Table3  2   DeptId    00002
Table3  2   DeptHead  Nik
```

First column is the table name then primary key then actual column name of table and then the column value. As per the above example Table1 have 3 columns which are Name,SId,City. There are 2 rows for Table1 which we can get using the value 1 and 2(primary keys). Same way goes for Table2 and Table3.
I have to fetch all the details from the file and then first join Table1 and Table2 rows using SId and then with Table3 using DeptId to create one common record.Likewise there are thousands of entries in the text file. There are also around 20 tables. The above is just an example.

Till now I have created a a class

```
 public class Student
 {
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnValue { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
 }

public class Program
{
    private static bool IsAllColumnsExist(DataTable tableNameToCheck, List<string> columnsNames)
    {
        var iscolumnExist = true;
        if (tableNameToCheck != null && tableNameToCheck.Columns != null)
        {
            foreach (string columnName in columnsNames)
            {
                if (!tableNameToCheck.Columns.Contains(columnName))
                {
                    iscolumnExist = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            iscolumnExist = false;
        }
        return iscolumnExist;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var table1 = new DataTable();
        var table2 = new DataTable();
        var table3 = new DataTable();

        var tablesData = (from line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Console.txt")
                           let values = line.Split('\t')
                           select new Toyo
                           {
                               TableName = values[0].ToString(),
                               PrimaryKey = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]),
                               ColumnName = values[2].ToString(),
                               ColumnValue = values[3].ToString()
                           }).ToList();



        var groupedData = tablesData.GroupBy(x => new { x.TableName,x.PrimaryKey }).ToList();
        foreach (var tableData in groupedData)
        {
            var primaryKey = tableData.Select(x => x.PrimaryKey).First();
            var columnNames = tableData.Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList();
            var columnValues = tableData.Select(x => x.ColumnValue).ToList();
            if (tableData.All(x => x.TableName == "Table1"))
            {
                if (!IsAllColumnsExist(table1, columnNames))
                {
                    table1.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("pkTable1", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[0], typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[1], typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[2], typeof(string))
                    });
                }
                table1.Rows.Add(primaryKey, columnValues[0], columnValues[1], columnValues[2]);
            }
            else if (tableData.All(x => x.TableName == "Table2"))
            {
                if (!IsAllColumnsExist(table2, columnNames))
                {
                    table2.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("pkTable2", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[0], typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[1], typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[2], typeof(string))
                    });
                }
                table2.Rows.Add(primaryKey, columnValues[0], columnValues[1], columnValues[2]);
            }
            else if (tableData.All(x => x.TableName == "Table3"))
            {
                if (!IsAllColumnsExist(table3, columnNames))
                {
                    table3.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3]
                    {
                        new DataColumn("pkTable3", typeof(int)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[0], typeof(string)),
                        new DataColumn(columnNames[1], typeof(string))
                    });
                }
                table3.Rows.Add(primaryKey, columnValues[0], columnValues[1]);
            }
        }


        var result = (from firstTable in table1.AsEnumerable()
                      join secondTable in table2.AsEnumerable() on firstTable.Field<string>("SId") equals secondTable.Field<string>("SId")
                      join thirdTable in table3.AsEnumerable() on secondTable.Field<string>("DeptId") equals thirdTable.Field<string>("DeptId")
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = firstTable.Field<string>("Name"),
                          StudentId = firstTable.Field<string>("SId"),
                          City = firstTable.Field<string>("City"),
                          DepartmentName = secondTable.Field<string>("DeptName"),
                          DepartmentId = secondTable.Field<string>("DeptId"),
                          DepartmentHead = thirdTable.Field<string>("DeptHead")
                      }).ToList();
    }
}
```

But in this way I have to create data table for each table. And in my exact problem there are around 20 tables which will make it to bad code to create 20 data tables as above.

Is there a better way to do this?
Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Can we assume there will be a 1:1 mapping from Table1 through to all the tables?

Comment: Can I assume there will only be one column in common between two tables (e.g. foreign keys are always one field)?

Answer (score 0):

I would indeed create 20 DataTables, but I would store them in a dictionary for easy access. It will also make your program more flexible.

So the data type to use:

```
Dictionary<string, DataTable>
```

More on [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ya we can do  that. But is it a good code in this particular scenario?

Comment: I guess so, but instead of the tableN, you can just use the table name as key in the dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by table N? Didnt get u.

Comment: table1, tabke2, etc

Comment: Then how instead of this?

Comment: Read up on the concepts of dictionary.  Create one. When you read a line, find the appropriate DataTable in the dictionary. If it doesn't exist, add one and fill it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the columns of each of the tables the same? `DeptId` `DeptHead`, etc exist in each of the tables? And are these columns 'fixed' (ie you can't just arbitrarily get a column name that you're not expecting)? If so, I would create a class structure to represent the columns, and one column titled `TableId`, and import the data into that, either in memory as a List or persist to a database.

It looks like you are trying to do aggregate functions on the data (group by TableId), so I feel this would be the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you only need to keep one value from any overlapping column names between tables. I am assuming the first table in the file can be used to source the primary keys for the common, final table. I assume there is only one common field between linked tables using the same name as the foreign key.

I wrote the code to be completely dynamic. I am assuming you need the intermediate `DataTable`s as well as the final combined `DataTable`, otherwise you could just dynamically map the incoming data into records and then combine them into the final `DataTable`.

My approach is to use LINQ to convert the text file lines into anonymous objects and then process the objects to extract all table names, then column names for each table and build the `DataTable`s and load the data into each one.

I build a common `DataTable` based on all the column names for all the tables.

Then I find the common field between each table (assuming one). I index the `DataTable`s by the common (foreign key) field so I can easily lookup the rows (e.g. home grown join implementation) and then join each record into one combined record and put it into the combined table.

```
// load textfile and convert lines into objects
//  var inFile = File.ReadLines(...);
var inData = inFile.Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
                   .Select(lineArray => new {
                       TableName = lineArray[0],
                       PrimaryKey = lineArray[1],
                       ColName = lineArray[2],
                       ColValue = lineArray[3],
                   });

// Buld a dictionary of tables and their columns
var tableColNames = inData.Select(r => new { r.TableName, r.ColName })
                          .Distinct()
                          .GroupBy(r => r.TableName, r => r.ColName)
                          .ToDictionary(rg => rg.Key, rg => rg.Select(r => r).ToList());
var tableNames = tableColNames.Keys.ToList();

// build all of the tables into a dictionary of tables
var dataTables = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
foreach (var tableName in tableNames) {
    var aTable = new DataTable(tableName);
    var primaryKeyCol = new DataColumn("PrimaryKey");
    aTable.Columns.Add(primaryKeyCol);
    aTable.PrimaryKey = new[] { primaryKeyCol };
    foreach (var colName in tableColNames[tableName]) {
        aTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(colName));
    }
    dataTables[tableName] = aTable;
}

// load all of the tables with their data
foreach (var aTable in dataTables.Values) {
    var inRows = inData.Where(r => r.TableName == aTable.TableName)
                       .GroupBy(r => r.PrimaryKey);
    foreach (var row in inRows) {
        var newRow = aTable.NewRow();
        newRow["PrimaryKey"] = row.Key;
        foreach (var col in row)
            newRow[col.ColName] = col.ColValue;
        aTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
}

// build the combined table with all columns
var combinedTable = new DataTable();
foreach (var aTable in dataTables.Values)
    combinedTable.Columns.AddRange(aTable.DataColumns()
                                         .Where(dc => !combinedTable.ColumnNames()
                                                                    .Contains(dc.ColumnName))
                                         .Select(dc => new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName))
                                         .ToArray());

// find and index the common columns between tables
var commonColNames = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(); // [TableName]=>[LinkedTableName]=>ColumnName
var indexes = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DataRow>>(); // [TableName]=>[ColumnValue]=>DataRow
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < tableNames.Count; ++j1) { // foreach table, find its linked tables
    var startTableName = tableNames[j1];
    var startTable = dataTables[startTableName];
    var startTableColNames = startTable.NonPrimaryKeyColumnNames().ToList();
    var linkedTables = tableNames.Skip(j1 + 1) // only find links to later tables
                                     .Select(n => (TableName: n, CommonColName: startTableColNames.Intersect(dataTables[n].ColumnNames()).SingleOrDefault()))
                                     .Where(tc => tc.CommonColName != null);

    if (linkedTables.Count() > 0) { // if it has linked tables, save the linking column and index that column
        var linkingColNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // [LinkedTableName]=>ColumnName
        foreach (var linkedTable in linkedTables) {
            linkingColNames.Add(linkedTable.TableName, linkedTable.CommonColName);
            if (!indexes.ContainsKey(linkedTable.TableName)) { // only build indexes once per linking column
                var colIndex = dataTables[linkedTable.TableName].AsEnumerable()
                                                                  .Select(r => (Key: r.Field<string>(linkedTable.CommonColName), DataRow: r))
                                                                  .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.DataRow);
                indexes.Add(linkedTable.TableName, colIndex);
            }
        }
        commonColNames[startTableName] = linkingColNames;
    }
}

// combine the tables starting with the first table
var firstTableName = tableNames[0];
var firstTable = dataTables[firstTableName];
var firstTableColNames = firstTable.ColumnNames().ToList();
// foreach DataRow in the first table
foreach (var r1 in firstTable.AsEnumerable()) {
    var newRow = combinedTable.NewRow();
    // load the first table DataRow into the combined DataRow
    newRow.CopyColumnValues(r1, firstTableColNames);

    // find all the linked tables and merge their DataRows into the combined DataRow
    var linkedTableNamesStack = new Stack<(string TableName, string LinkedTableName)>();
    linkedTableNamesStack.PushRange(commonColNames[firstTableName].Keys.Select(ltn => (firstTableName,ltn)));
    while (linkedTableNamesStack.Count > 0) {
        var nextTableLink = linkedTableNamesStack.Pop();
        if (commonColNames.TryGetValue(nextTableLink.LinkedTableName, out var linkedTables))
            linkedTableNamesStack.PushRange(linkedTables.Keys.Select(ltn => (nextTableLink.LinkedTableName,ltn)));
        var linkingColName = commonColNames[nextTableLink.TableName][nextTableLink.LinkedTableName];
        var linkingColValue = newRow.Field<string>(linkingColName);
        var linkedRow = indexes[nextTableLink.LinkedTableName][linkingColValue];
        newRow.CopyColumnValues(linkedRow, linkedRow.Table.NonPrimaryKeyColumnNames());
    }
    combinedTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Here are the extension methods used:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<string> NonPrimaryKeyColumnNames(this DataTable aTable) => aTable.ColumnNames().Where(n => n != "PrimaryKey");

    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> DataColumns(this DataTable aTable) => aTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
    public static IEnumerable<string> ColumnNames(this DataTable aTable) => aTable.DataColumns().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName);
    public static void CopyColumnValues(this DataRow dest, DataRow src, IEnumerable<string> colNames) {
        foreach (var colName in colNames)
            dest[colName] = src[colName];
    }

    public static void PushRange<T>(this Stack<T> s, IEnumerable<T> Ts) => Ts.ForEach(aT => s.Push(aT));
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
        foreach (var s in source)
            action(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for the help. But I think for join it will be easy to use the dictionary and then take table data from the key which is TableName and then join all the three tables like that using AsEnumerable().

Comment: @sixsigma And pre-program the joining column names for each table?